Apache Camel 3.21.0+: Endpoint not Processing Values from URL Parameters Correctly
After upgrading to Apache Camel version 3.21.0 and higher, I'm encountering an issue where my endpoints are not processing values correctly from URL parameters. Specifically, I have a URL like http://localhost:8080/rest/Models/BASE/FR/CA/2017/CA, which should provide values for segments like /walk//locales/_/years//divisions//modelYears.
When I make a request to an endpoint like http://project/search/walk//locales/_/years//divisions//modelYears, I'm receiving a 404 error with the message: HTTP operation failed invoking
http://project/search/walk//locales/_/years//divisions//modelYears with statusCode: 404
In previous versions of Apache Camel and up to version 3.20.7, my setup worked correctly. It seems that Apache Camel 3.21.0+ is not interpreting or mapping the URL parameters correctly, resulting in empty segments (//) where values should be populated.
Could someone shed light on:

What changes have been made in Apache Camel 3.21.0 and higher related to URL parameter handling?

What configurations or adjustments are needed to ensure Apache Camel 3.21.0+ correctly processes and maps URL parameters to endpoints?


I've reviewed the documentation but haven't found specific changes that explain this behavior. Any insights, explanations, or references to updated documentation would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
I tried looking at apache camel migration documentations, but nothing useful was mentioned.
